# How to pull the column name in to the data in SAS

Tags: sas

The table with date as a variable name with respect to **VOL**, I want to create a new variable as **FLAG** that IF variables having 1 pull the date of the variable name in to the **FLAG** column

```
  VOL   31-Dec-10   31-Dec-11   31-Dec-12   31-Dec-13   31-Dec-14   31-Dec-15
109001  0   0   0   0   1   0
109002  0   0   1   0   0   0
109003  0   0   1   0   0   0
109004  0   0   0   1   0   0
109006  0   0   1   0   0   1
```

output

```
 VOL    31-Dec-10   31-Dec-11   31-Dec-12   31-Dec-13   31-Dec-14   31-Dec-15   FLAG
109001  0   0   0   0   1   0   31-Dec-14
109002  0   0   1   0   0   0   31-Dec-12
109003  0   0   1   0   0   0   31-Dec-12
109004  0   0   0   1   0   0   31-Dec-13
109006  0   0   1   0   0   1   31-Dec-15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `vlabel()` function since those column headings don't meet standard variable name requirements and I'm assuming they're labels.  Below is example code to put in a data step, but you'll have to know the actual variable names for the array declaration and replace `date1--date99` with them.

```
array mydates (*) date1--date99;
do over mydates;
    if mydates = 1 then flag = vlabel(mydates);
end;
```

The way this loop is written, it will leave the date of the rightmost occurrence of `1`, which seems consistent with your example in the 19006 row.

See also `vname()`.